# Problems with <form> in Safari - only first click will POST to _blank target

Tags: php, forms, post, safari

I am using PHP to generate 10 forms on a page which attach an image as the button and POST hidden values to a _blank target. This works ok in Firefox, all 10 buttons submit and post to a new window. In Safari however only the first button i click will work (whichever one I choose) after that none of the buttons (forms) submit and POST to a new window (!!! whats going on??)

Heres the code -

```
$id=getId();
echo "<form name=\"clickthrough$id\" action=\"click_through.php\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_blank\"><input type=\"image\" src=\"images/buttons/buynow_a.gif\" name=\"buynow\"/><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"".$id."\"/></form>";
```

Nothing strange here - the id is actually the id of a song in my database which i have simplified for showing here - but I included it on the end of the form name just incase this was causing the problem.

So to recap I end up with 10 buy now buttons on a page - all of which should post through to a PHP script. The scripts work fine. However in safari once i have pressed any buy now button all of the others stop working (until I refresh the page)

why is this?

-- here is the final html that is generated for the buttons

```
<form name="clickthrough1728" action="click_through.php" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="image" src="images/buttons/buynow_a.gif" name="buynow"/><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1728"/><input type="hidden" name="location" value="UK"/></form>

<form name="clickthrough1724" action="click_through.php" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="image" src="images/buttons/buynow_a.gif" name="buynow"/><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1724"/><input type="hidden" name="location" value="UK"/></form>

<form name="clickthrough1718" action="click_through.php" method="POST" target="_blank"><input type="image" src="images/buttons/buynow_a.gif" name="buynow"/><input type="hidden" name="id" value="1718"/><input type="hidden" name="location" value="UK"/></form>
```

....

I have just tried copying this to a new html file and testing and the same thing happens - the first click will open a new window but no buttons after that will post the form

Comment: Can you show the finished, generated HTML code of the 10 forms?

Comment: Ive added the generated HTML to my question... note I am using Safari 5 on a PC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Quick check with the following code works just fine
(Safari 5 on Mac)

```
for($id = 1; $id < 11; $id++) {
   echo "<form name=\"clickthrough$id\" action=\"sandbox/_TestServer.php\" method=\"POST\" target=\"_blank\">
   <input type=\"image\" src=\"images/buttons/buynow_a.gif\" name=\"buynow\"/>
   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"".$id."\"/>
   </form>";
}
```

so it could be your `$id`. Generate the html and show it like Pekka suggested

**Edit**
I can't tell you what goes wrong in safari-windows-land 
but i've changed the code as follows an tested it on a VM (Win XP, Safari5) and it works:

```
for($id = 1; $id < 11; $id++) {
   echo "<form name=\"clickthrough$id\" action=\"_TestServer.php?$id\" method=\"post\" target=\"_blank\">
   <input type=\"image\" src=\"add.png\" name=\"buynow\"/>
   <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"".$id."\"/>
   </form>";
}
```

every form got its "unique" action target `?$id` and this seams to do the trick

**Edit** Link and Files removed

Comment: This is still a problem on Win XP, there's a Safari bug first reported in 2009. It happens with one form as well, where it can't be submitted a second time. For a single form, a similar approach is used. The form action can be updated after each submission to allow multiple submissions. See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6050218/751619

Comment: Your approach of adding salt to the action attribute of the form (via querystring) fixed this for me on iOS safari.

Answer (score 1):

Initial guess: the `_blank` isn't being treated as a special value, but instead is being treated as the same window, so that the first post goes to a new window, and subsequent ones (try to) go to the first window.

I would try giving each button a target of `_blank_$i` or something, so that each button has a unique target.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is due to the doctype you're using for the page. The target attribute is deprecated and is only available in XHTML Transitional, XHTML Frameset or HTML 4. Are you using XHTML Strict? Maybe that would cause this strangeness, although it seems like a shot in the dark...

Comment: Thanks for your response - here is the doctype line fro my header - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

So I guess its not XHTML strict, should I be using that?

Comment: .... OK I tried to use this doctype in the header - 

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

But to no avail, still the same problem :(

Comment: Sorry, I guess that wasn't the problem then. HTML 4 should be fine with the target attribute in a form element. I thought it was worth a try. I'll post back if I have any more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a way to do this in Javascript. Try adding this code in your form element:

```
<form onsubmit="window.open('about:blank', 'somename', 'width=300,height=300)" target="somename"<!-- Rest of form code here -->>
```

You would obviously need a uniquely named window for each form and to reference that window in the target. This should degrade pretty well too. In the event of Javascript not being available it should behave as your code does currently, with the problems on Safari on a PC. Depending on how many users you have using that browser this may or may not be acceptable to you.