# Second form.submit() doesn't work in Safari on XP, works on other browsers

Tags: javascript, safari

I have some code that uses a form.submit() to open up another window when you click something on my page.  It works fine in IE 6-8, Firefox and Chrome, and Safari on Mac.  But in Safari on Windows XP, after you click that something, none of the other links that do form.submit() work.  Even the *same* something doesn't do it.  Here's some of the callback code for that button:

```
accessEmployeeViewClicked = function() {
    var form=document.Form<xsl:value-of select="//PAGE/@NAME" />;

    form.action = 'ServletName';
    form.target = "otherTarget";
    form.submit();
};
```

The function is accessed by the following code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="accessEmployeeViewClicked();return false;">Access employee's view &gt;&gt;</a>
```

I put a breakpoint in the Safari built-in debugger, and the second time you click it, it definitely gets into the `accessEmployeeViewClicked()` function, but the `form.submit();` does nothing.  As per the suggestion in the comments, I changed the form.target to "_blank" but that had no effect.

I've looked at these similar questions:

- [Firefox handles xxx.submit(), Safari doesn't ... what can be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333329/firefox-handles-xxx-submit-safari-doesnt-what-can-be-done)
- [document.form.submit(); won't submit in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410296/document-form-submit-wont-submit-in-safari)

and tried the suggestions, and they don't help.

Comment: Are you sure - try to change `form.target = "otherTarget";` to `form.target = "_blank";` - also please show the links that execute

Comment: The link that executes is, as you might expect from the above `<a href="#" onclick="accessEmployeeViewClicked()">Access employee's view</a>`

Comment: Changing the form.target to "_blank" didn't help.  Neither did changing the onclick to `"accessEmployeeViewClicked(); return false;"`

Comment: That was my next suggestion. Good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears Apple must be aware of the problem, since it was logged in 2009 and supposedly went into their "radar" bug tracking system, but they must not care:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28633

I implemented the work-around from that bug report, and it worked:

```
        form.action = 'ServletName';
        // Work around for Safari bug suggested in https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28633
        if ($.browser.safari)
        {
            form.action += '?t=' + new Date().getTime();
        }
        form.target = "otherTarget";
        form.submit();
```

Comment: And as you can see from that link, Apple has finally fixed the bug in the latest versions of Safari.

Comment: Have you noticed irritating caching issues in mobile safari (iPhone/iPad) ? When I get an update to a link with an anchor, the page does not refresh

Comment: It was still broken for me in recent iOS Safari. The salt-in-the-action workaround still works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler solution - will work on all browsers and give you an added value of a timestamp in your log file

```
<form onsubmit="this.ts.value=new Date().getTime()">
.
.
.
<input type="hidden" name="ts" value="timestamp" />
</form>
```

If you have the function do the submit, the onsubmit is not triggered so instead add

```
form.target = "otherTarget";
form.ts.value=new Date().getTime()
form.submit();
```