# Open and refresh after a form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, safari

I write a code to do this :

On the page, there is a button when the user click on it, he will launch a new window (_blank) and in the same time refresh (_self) the current page with another link.

Here is the html code on page

```
<form name="reveal-form" id="reveal-form" action="<?php echo $current_url; ?>" method="post" charset="UTF-8" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="yes" />
<div>
<a onClick="SubmitForm('<?php echo $current_url; ?>','/go?id=311364','reveal-form');">
<span>launch</span>
</a>
</div>
</form>
```

And the javascript code

```
function SubmitForm( url, url2, name)
{
     document.forms[name].action=url;
     document.forms[name].target='_blank';
     document.forms[name].submit();

     document.forms[name].action=url2;
     document.forms[name].target='_self';
     document.forms[name].submit();
     return true;
}
```

This code works with chrome 32, firefox 26 but not in safari 7 do you have any idea for this problem? Safari only take the _self link but don't want to open the blank window. Thanks for your inputs!

Edit : in my test safari don't use the javascript very strange

Comment: See if this helps to solve your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6050218/1040188

Comment: If I am getting your question correctly, you want to refresh after submitting the form then its better to use window.location.href

Comment: Yes for the refresh but I want to use another url like that : url1 : the button => url2 the refresh on url1 and url3 on _blank